# Where the `prototype` property is defined

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

Well, all the time i supposed that prototype property exists at all objects. But after one of job interview i came home and open chrome console

```
window.prototype
**undefined**
```

WTF?

```
Object.prototype
**Object {}**
```

OK

```
var a = {};
a.prototype
**undefined**

var a = function(){}
a.prototype
**Object {}**
```

I've read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype several times but still not clear. Can anybody explain?

Thanx

P.S. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

> All objects in JavaScript are descended from Object; all objects
>   inherit methods and properties from Object.prototype, although they
>   may be overridden (except an Object with a null prototype, i.e.
>   Object.create(null)

window is Object, so it must have prototype property

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The object an instance inherits from, its prototype, is stored in an internal property, [`[[Prototype]]`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2). Its value can be retrieved with [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.2) (in ES5-compatible engines).

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(window));
// Window { ... }

var a = {};
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(a));
// Object { ... }
```

Only `function`s explicitly have a [`prototype` property](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.5.2):

```
console.log(typeof Object);
// 'function'
```

And, the value of the `prototype` is just used to set the value of the instance's `[[Prototype]]` when a `new` instance is created.

```
function Foo() {}
var bar = new Foo();

console.log(Foo.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(bar)); // true
```

Comment: and what about access by .prototype notation?  I think, Object.getPrototypeOf return ._proto_ property isnt it?

Comment: @VasilVanchuk, myObject.__proto__ does the same thing as Object.getPrototypeOf(myObject) in older browsers, but is deprecated. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: @VasilVanchuk 1) `Function`s only have a `prototype` property so instances inherit that from object instead of the constructor itself. But, any object can be used as the prototype of another ([`Object.create()`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.5)), so a `prototype` property isn't otherwise necessary and won't generally be found. 2) And, yeah, `getPrototypeOf()` and `__proto__` will provide the same value. But, `__proto__` is non-standard and has been deprecated in some supporting browsers.

Comment: About "Functions only have a prototype property" - i supposed so, can you give me some proof link? Thx